# Django admin changelist view used in the users site

Tags: python, django

Basically the admin changelist view has a lot of nice features like sorting, filtering, field list, pagination...

Can I borrow that functionality and use it in my public users site? I was thinking to have class-based view called Cars and borrow all those features from the admin site.

I thought that ModelAdmin would be a place to look, but I have no idea to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

The [django-table2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2) app is more reasonable option for such task than the admin's changelist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I ended up using django admin for this site instead of developing a public site. Plus on top of this I used django-grappelli to customize the dashboard and make it look like a custom site.
So now I have two admin sites:
1- is the default django/grappelli site that has all the links and functions of the traditional admin site. and this was only used by developers and super users

2- a custom admin site called dashboard that looks more user friendly, and have customized all the look and feel, plus it has the change list, change form of my models so I don't have to rewrite these functions.

and this is how it looks now:

[image]